# Low resolution after installing CUDA drivers

Tags: linux, drivers, linux-mint, cuda, optimus

I'm trying to setup a working CUDA SDK on my Linux Mint. I'm new to Linux and everything connected with it. So, I tried following some steps on how to install CUDA. Firstly, I downloaded a Linux driver from here: http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-downloads version 295.41. After that, I barely found a way to run it.

I did it like this:

1. typed in `sudo init 1` in terminal and switched to root
2. typed `service mdm stop`
3. ran the *.run file downloaded from the link above

Then it started installing the driver. It gave some warning messages, but I ignored it. After installation, I typed `init 5` and it came back to GUI screen, BUT everything is huge. I restarted, still huge. My screen resolution is 640x480 on a 17 inch laptop monitor.

I tried running Nvidia X server Settings, but it says: "You do not appear to be using Nvidia X Driver. Please edit your X configuration file." I tried that. Nothing happened. I cant change the resolution because that Nvidia Settings thing gives no options.
Then I googled some things, installing some packages - nothing. The biggest problem is I don't understand whats really going on.

My laptop is a Samsung with i7 and Nvidia Gt 650M with optimus. I cant even install bumblebee, but that is something I will try if I manage to get my resolution to default. Please, help!

Comment: This is off topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to install a working driver using this tutorial:
http://eternalvoid.net/tutorials/linux-optimus-gt650m/

Answer (score 0):

Well. Go through the following three steps:

1) Try to reboot and boot into the system in run-level 1 initially and get the command line.

2) Run 'init 3'

3) Install the nvidia driver and admit the question about overwriting the xconfiguration file.

4) Reboot normally

Now you should have clean driver installation with normal screen.

Comment: Okay. So, what I did is I booted Mint, pressed ctrl+alt+f1 on the log in screen, logged in and then I typed "init 3" and then I tried to run the driver but it said: "It seems you are running X server." and exited. That is the problem. When I type in init 1, instalation goes through, but as I already said, everything is messed up. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Does Mint have /etc/inittab (to change default run-level)?

Comment: Nope. I tried googling that and there is nothing about changing run levels in Mint like that. There is no inittab file. :(

Comment: Open new terminal (using Ctrl+Alt+F1) and then kill the X by 'service gdm stop'. Does it kill the X?

Comment: It says unknown service. If you're thinking about killing the display manager, I can do it by typing service mdm stop, but then nothing happens. I mean, everything goes black and a white underscore keeps blinking at the top left of the screen and the only thing I can do then is press the power button and it shuts off. Doesn't react to any other typing or anything.

Comment: I think this happens if you kill the display manager inside itself terminal (F7). If you could kill the X by other terminals (F1 to F6), you can take the control of system without X. Then you just give 'init 3' and install driver easily. I remember that I had the same problem in uBuntu. I boot the ubuntu in recovery mode and changed the run-level there to 3. Can you boot in recovery mode?

Comment: I can boot to recovery, but I have no idea on how to change run level to 1 there. Or 3. Or any other.

Comment: Boot in recovery and then you see the option of 'root command line' or something similar. Then the system is booted in run-level 1 so quickly. When you saw the command line available, run 'init 3' and then continue and install the driver. Finally, reboot and continue normally.

Comment: I did that. When I typed in init 3, it started some things and then said something like: "Your X server couldn't start because of some error. The display will be shutdown." And it freezes there. :(

Comment: I am running out of idea! What about installing just as recovery starts in runlevel 1? (before entering 'init 3')

Comment: Tried that. It refuses even starting that because of some "read only" problems (whatever I try in that mode is refused saying something about read only). I guess it sets the whole disk as read only in that mode. Ah well, I'll just go back to Ubuntu or something. Hope Ubuntu will work. Thanks anyway man!